# Memory access violation while passing void* param to DLL function

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm adding new disk device to system from my C# code, so I want to call

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public extern static void SHChangeNotify(long wEventId, uint uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);
```

like below

```
MyWin32Functions.SHChangeNotify(0x00000100/*ADDRIVE*/, 0x0005/*PATHW*/, driveLetter, IntPtr.Zero);
```

dwItem1 is void* and we should pass a wchar_t* (pointing to null terminated string) containing drive root in this case; so driveLetter above is

```
        string letter = "Z:\\";

        byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(letter);
        byte[] zdata = new byte[data.Length + 1];
        data.CopyTo(zdata, 0);

        IntPtr p = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(zdata.Length);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(zdata, 0, p, zdata.Length);
```

(my code almost same as code in similiar case: [How to call SHChangeNotify from C# without error 14007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051674/how-to-call-shchangenotify-from-c-sharp-without-error-14007)
but I get System.AccessViolationException)

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if that is the issue, but I think the wEventID argument is supposed to be a uint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter in your interop signature should be an `int`, not a `long`. Though the Win32 function is declared as LONG, a LONG in Win32 is 32-bit.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
public extern static void SHChangeNotify(int wEventId, uint uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);
```

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows the common mapping between Win32 types an .NET types for Platform Invoke.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that helped! Haven't even dug in this direction, I thought problem was in marshalling a string.

Comment: `SetLastError = true` is also wrong. The docs make no mention of `GetLastError`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Oops, I didn't see that. I removed the unnecessary flags in the DllImportAttribute.